# How to Use Intent() no-args constructor

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-context

How can I set the `Context` (the first parameter in the `Intent(Context, Class)` constructor),

How can I set this `context` after creating an instance of an `intent` with it's empty constructor!?

**UPDATE :**

You mean that I can't set the context "alone"?

I need to set the context first, then after some steps I can set the class?

Comment: setClass(context,class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the `Context`. An `Intent` doesn't need a `Context`. You only need to pass a `Context` in the particular variants of the constructor that also take a `Class` parameter (there are several available constructors):

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

The reason that you need to pass a `Context` here is that the constructor uses the `Context` and `Class` parameters to set the `Component` in the `Intent`. To set the `Component`, the constructor needs to have the **package name** and the **class name** (both are of type `String`). It can get the class name from the `Class` parameter, and it uses the `Context` to get the package name.

You have several alternatives. You can use an empty `Intent` constructor and set the `Component` later using any of these methods:

```
setClassName (String packageName, String className)
setClassName (Context packageContext, String className)
setClass (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
setComponent (ComponentName component);
```

Comment: then you mean, instead of calling new Intent().setContext(this) ... which is not available, i can create the ComponentName, and pass it to that intent at any time ... i hope i got it right, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can set context & class like below...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(your_context, YourActivity.class);
```

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`intent.setClass(Context, class)` ?

EDIT

use your logic first, context will probably remain the same so decide which class you want to declare and then add it together with the context, if this is more complex issue please provide more information about your flow